# Javascript: How do I replace text between two delimiters?

Tags: javascript

```
var record = "HENRY|5|58|L581"
```

How do I change the above to:

```
record now equals "HENRY|Five|58|L581"
```

I know how to retrieve the index of the first '|' and the second '|'  .. I know how to retrieve the number '5' into a string.

But I have no idea how to actually replace that 5 with the word Five.

The part |5| could be any number from 1-50

Comment: If it's any number, do you still want to replace it with FIVE ?

Comment: If it's any number from 1 to 50 , you should first have an array of strings from 'one' to 'fifty' , then take the number , add one to it and find the string at that particular index , fetch the string and do the replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
var record = "HENRY|5|58|L581"

var recordArray = record.split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < recordArray.length; i++) {
     if (recordArray[i] === "5") {
          recordArray[i] = "FIVE";
     }
}
record = recordArray.join("|"); // or record = recordArray.toString();
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

**UPDATE**

If you want any number, you can set it into a function:

```
function changeNumber(textVar, valueToChange, replaceText) {

    var recordArray = textVar.split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < recordArray.length; i++) {
        if (recordArray[i] === valueToChange) {
             recordArray[i] = replaceText;
        }
    }
    return recordArray.join("|"); // or recordArray.toString();
}
```

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KKyWY/2/)**.

Comment: How would I get this into a variable after what you suggested? recordChanged = "HENRY|five|58|L581" .... like this

Comment: this is so close but the variable is no longer just a normal variable it's an array right? how do I get the array back into a regular string variable again?

Comment: @Gast1 Yes, it will be an array variable, but you can use `.join()` (recommended) or `.toString()` to return it as string or assign it to your variable. With the function you can work like `var record = "some|5|thing"; record = changeNumber(record, 5, "FIVE");` or use it into an `alert` like my demo.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that ?

```
record = record.replace('|5|', '|FIVE|');
```

Following edit :

To replace any number by FIVE, you can do

```
record = record.replace(/\|\d+\|/, '|FIVE|');
```

If you want to replace with something depending of the number (maybe you want TEN when the number is 10), then you'll have to do some work :

```
record = record.replace(/\|\d+\|/, function(str) {
     var number = parseInt(str,10);
     return 'FIVE'; // here build a new string and return it
});
```

Comment: The problem is there might be another |5| somewhere in the record. I need to make sure I change the |5| in the start of the string.

Comment: That was before your edit in which you says you want to replace any number.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you don't want to replace any number with "five", you want to replace with the actual string representing number.

```
var repl = [0, 1, ....];
var to = ["zero", "one", ...];
var recordArray = record.split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < recordArray.length; i++) {
 recordArray[i] = to[indexOf(recordArray[i], repl)];
}

finStr = recordArray.join("|");
```